# C# Filling rectangle leaves a white space

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I have a C# winforms where Im drawing a rectangle and then I fill it.

Here is the code:

```
LinearGradientBrush secondGradient = new LinearGradientBrush(frontRect, Color.FromArgb(255, 190, 171, 18), Color.FromArgb(255, 152, 186, 27), 90);

     /* second row element */
                    g.DrawRectangle(pen, leftInsertionBox);
                    g.FillRectangle(secondGradient, leftInsertionBox.X + 1, leftInsertionBox.Y + 1, leftInsertionBox.Width - 1, leftInsertionBox.Height - 1);

                    g.DrawRectangle(pen, leftCoverBox);
                    g.FillRectangle(secondGradient, leftCoverBox.X + 1, leftCoverBox.Y + 1, leftCoverBox.Width - 1, leftCoverBox.Height - 1);
                    /* second row element */
```

The problem is that I can see like a pixel of white space between my rectangle line and the fill.

[image]

> Any clue on how to solve this?

Comment: First `Fill` the whole rectangle (remove +1 offsets), then `Draw`

Comment: I can't see the image because imgur is blocked for me, but have you tried it with a SolidBrush?

Comment: Have you tried doing the operations in the reverse order? I'd try doing the fill, without any offset calculations (i.e. fill the entire rectangle) and then draw the border after.

Comment: Reversing was the right solution @itsme86, do you want to set that as the solution?

Comment: Note that the source of the problem is the buggy DrawRectangle that always overdraws by one pixel to the right and bottom. Corrctions should go there, not to the FillRectangles!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try reversing the operations. Do the fill operation first, removing the offset calculations (i.e. fill the entire region) and then draw the border.

```
g.FillRectangle(secondGradient, leftInsertionBox.X, leftInsertionBox.Y, leftInsertionBox.Width, leftInsertionBox.Height);
g.DrawRectangle(pen, leftInsertionBox);

g.FillRectangle(secondGradient, leftCoverBox.X, leftCoverBox.Y, leftCoverBox.Width, leftCoverBox.Height);
g.DrawRectangle(pen, leftCoverBox);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the extra pixel that you added.